# How to Get a column name from excel and bind it in the Checkboxlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I want to bind the Excel Column Names To Checkboxlist.

If i try to bind all the excel sheet will be bind.

I want To bind only Column name to CheckBoxlist

Answer (score 0):

I can barely read this, let alone understand a question.  However, I think you want to have a `CheckBoxList` of Excel column names.  I don't understand the part about "binding" as that would be implementation specific.  You could get the names of the columns from Excel, but in my experience, this c# function is much quicker and provides the same answers:

```
public static string Column(int number, bool entire = false)
{
    string columnString = string.Empty;
    decimal columnNumber = number;
    while (columnNumber > 0)
    {
        decimal currentLetterNumber = (columnNumber - 1) % 26;
        char currentLetter = (char)(currentLetterNumber + 65);
        columnString = currentLetter + columnString;
        columnNumber = (columnNumber - (currentLetterNumber + 1)) / 26;
    }

    if (entire)
    {
        return columnString + ":" + columnString;
    }
    else
    {
        return columnString;
    }
}
```